# simple method to assign a multi-dimensional std::array with same value?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I am looking for a simple method to assign a multi-dimensional array with the same value? For example

```
using namespace std;

array<array<array<int, 2>, 3>, 4> a;
```

and want all elements of `a[:][:][:]` to be 10. I don't want use 3 loops. One loop is fine.

Comment: Nested calls to [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) or [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n)? Will still be three loops but they are "hidden" from view, and not especially "elegant".

Comment: [`array_view`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3851.pdf) ( part of [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) ) might be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplistic way would be

```
for (auto& a1:a) for (auto& a2:a1) for (auto& a3:a2)
    a3 = 10;
```

Slightly more direct, but less generic:

```
a = {{ 
    {{ {{ 10, 10 }}, {{ 10, 10 }}, {{ 10, 10 }} }},
    {{ {{ 10, 10 }}, {{ 10, 10 }}, {{ 10, 10 }} }},
    {{ {{ 10, 10 }}, {{ 10, 10 }}, {{ 10, 10 }} }},
    {{ {{ 10, 10 }}, {{ 10, 10 }}, {{ 10, 10 }} }},
}};
```

Finally, since `std::array<>` guarantees contiguous storage, you could "cheat" and do

```
std::fill(
    &*a.front().front().begin(),
    &*a.back().back().end(),
    10);
```

Interestingly, `clang` **[generates identical assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/adCJ0g)** for all three methods:

[image]

### Generalizing for *n-dimensional* arrays of `T`

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

namespace detail {
    struct nested_range_helper {
        template <typename T>           static auto array_inner_begin(T& o)                { return std::addressof(o); } 
        template <typename T, size_t N> static auto array_inner_begin(std::array<T, N>& o) { return array_inner_begin(o.front()); }

        template <typename T>           static auto array_inner_end  (T& o)                { return std::addressof(o) + 1; } 
        template <typename T, size_t N> static auto array_inner_end  (std::array<T, N>& o) { return array_inner_end(o.back()); }
    };
}

template <typename T> 
auto innermost_begin(T& v) { return detail::nested_range_helper::array_inner_begin(v); }
template <typename T> 
auto innermost_end(T& v) { return detail::nested_range_helper::array_inner_end(v); }

template <typename T, typename V> void method3(T& a, V v = V{}) {
    std::fill(innermost_begin(a), innermost_end(a), v);
}

int main() {
    std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 3>, 4> a;
    std::array<std::array<double, 7>, 21> b;

    method3(a, 10);
    method3(b, 3.14);
}
```

Still emitting the same optimized assembly when using clang: https://godbolt.org/g/d1kj3m

Comment: It's probably a case of premature optimization. Compilers optimize this, as you [can see](https://godbolt.org/g/sKPLf8)

Comment: And [here's a generalized version of `method3` for n-dimensional arrays](https://godbolt.org/g/d1kj3m). Observe how clang still optimizes to the same assembly for the OP's sample. Zero loops.

Comment: Love your thoroughness as always, @sehe!

Comment: @moodboom Ah - it took me forever to see what the edit did. Thanks for the fix :)